# Why am I getting only one message?

Tags: java, jms, activemq-classic

So I have a simple JMS app, using a topic, powered by activeMQ. It works, but  only 1 message is being sent (even though I am writing more lines in the console and so trying to send more stuff).

When I check the  web console of ActiveMq, only 1 message is being sent (I also get this message in the ReceiverTopic class)...Why is this happening?

Below you can see my sender code:

```
package topic;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

import javax.jms.Connection;
import javax.jms.ConnectionFactory;
import javax.jms.Destination;
import javax.jms.JMSException;
import javax.jms.Message;
import javax.jms.MessageConsumer;
import javax.jms.MessageListener;
import javax.jms.MessageProducer;
import javax.jms.Session;
import javax.jms.TextMessage;

import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnection;
import org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory;

public class SenderTopic {
  private ConnectionFactory factory = null;
  private Connection connection = null;
  private Session session = null;
  private Destination destination = null;
  private MessageProducer producer = null;

  private boolean jmsInitialized = false;

  public SenderTopic() {

  }

  private void initJMS() throws JMSException {
    factory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory(ActiveMQConnection.DEFAULT_BROKER_URL);
    connection = factory.createConnection();
    connection.start();
    session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
    destination = session.createTopic("SAMPLE_TOPIC");
    producer = session.createProducer(destination);
    jmsInitialized = true;
  }

  private void sendMessage(String message) {
    if (!jmsInitialized) {
      try {
        initJMS();
        sendTextMessage(message);
      } catch (JMSException e) {
        jmsInitialized = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }

  private void sendTextMessage(String message) throws JMSException {
    TextMessage textMessage = session.createTextMessage(message);
    producer.send(textMessage);
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    SenderTopic receiver = new SenderTopic();

    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    while (true) {
      String message = reader.readLine();
      receiver.sendMessage(message);
    }
  }

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Intially the value of `jmsInitialized` is `false`, so your if condition (`!jmsInitialized`) will be true.

On second call of `sendMessage` the value of `jmsInitialized` will be `true` and the if condition fails because you are using `not` on boolean value.

You can add a `else` condition with only call to `sendTextMessage`.

try out this

```
private void sendMessage(String message) {
 try {
    if (!jmsInitialized) {
        initJMS();
        sendTextMessage(message);
    }else{
        sendTextMessage(message);
    }
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        jmsInitialized = false;
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Damn...such a noobie mistake...I thought something was wrong with my JMS settings...Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Teshte My pleasure.. yeah sometimes it happens.